# .bashrc and fortune/cowsay

Tags: xubuntu, bashrc, fortune

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04 with XFCE (of course). I just added a line to `~/.bashrc`:

```
fortune | cowsay -f tux
```

And everything is fine, when I open a terminal, cowsay runs with a fortune quote. Except one problem: everytime my laptop startups, a wild terminal appears! (with cowsay).

I think all commands added to `.bashrc` will run only when I open a terminal, not when computer boots up, right? And I'm sure my session is not saved.

Anyone knows why? Thanks for reading, have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Put it into .bash_profile 
it is used for login shells, .bashrc is used more widely, eg also if you use scp from another machine, and, if you generate output in the .bashrc file, any scp and other will fail silently. they don't expect any output. .bash_profile would be only executed on login shells, eg virtual terminal, xterm,.....

Comment: 1. Ubuntu users have a `.profile` created for them, so if a `.bash_profile` is created, settings from `.profile` will be lost. 2. The default `.bashrc` on Ubuntu exits silently if not run by an interactive shell, so programs like `scp` shouldn't have problems. 3. I doubt xterm runs a login shell by default.